# Facebook popup authentication loses window.opener reference

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-login, window.opener, cross-origin-opener-policy

Our app allows users to login through Facebook. The page creates a popup which is redirected to FB login page (https://lm.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fconsent%2Fcomplete% ..., with header `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups;report-to="coop_report"`. At this point the window.opener reference is valid and points to original window. On desktop and iPhone the login then completes, redirects back to our page, with window.opener reference still valid.

However on Android (Chrome) when the popup redirects to our page it does so with `window.opener` set to `null`.
Meantime the only redirects are:
`https://m.facebook.com/dialog/consent/complete/` with `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none;report-to="coop_report"` header
and then back to our page without any COOP header.

There is one apperent difference - on Android a dialogue is shown that is not triggered on iPhone or desktop: "You previously logged in to ****** identity with Facebook. Would you like to continue?" On this dialogue the window still has the opener reference, and after it the above mentioned requests are fired.

I am not sure where exactly was the opener reference lost, or how can I prevent that, and why does it only happen with Android login process. I have found nothing in the Facebook documentation so far, and it seems to me that this could be a bug rather than a feature - however I still need to overcome it somehow.

Comment: Which Android _browser_? According to MDN, `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` has no support in Opera on Android yet. (And not in Android Webviews either, but I'm guessing you are not using those here?)

Comment: _"The page creates a popup which is redirected to FB login page"_ - is your own coding creating this popup - or are you using the JS SDK, and its `Fb.login()` method?

Comment: @CBroe I have been testing on Chrome (and also desktop Chrome with fake user-agent). We are not using JS SDK, the popup is created by our app.

Comment: Your"FB login page" URL there, is really rather weird. First of all, `https://lm.facebook.com/l.php` is Facebook's own "link shim" - its purpose is to redirect elsewhere, usually used by Facebook itself, for _external_ links. And why the redirection target then is `https://m.facebook.com/dialog/consent/complete/`, I also don't understand - [...]

Comment: [...] the usual way of invoking the login dialog, is via `https://www.facebook.com/vXX.Y/dialog/oauth`. I'm guessing Facebook realize that we are _not_ in a "/dialog/consent/complete/ state" here, and automatically redirect to the actual login dialog URL ... but it really doesn't make much sense to have so many redirects involved to begin with.